# Pygame display.set.mode not showing any display MacOS

Tags: python, pygame

So I recently installed pygame and started learning off youtube. The code that the youtuber was working on:

```
import pygame
# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

However, when he runs this, he gets a blank screen that runs, which is a result of  "pygame.display.set_mode".

But on my Mac, there is no blank screen, the Python Launcher simply jumps up and down on the dock without any display (there is no error showed either), anyone can help me understand why this is?

Basically what it looks like when I run it: The python launcher just jumps up and down in the dock -
[image]

What it should look like:
[image]

Comment: run script in console/terminal - `python script.py` - to see error messages.

Comment: @furas the code has no errors, it simply won't launch the window

Comment: did you run it manually in console/terminal ? Maybe it has any other problem and you would see it in console/terminal.

Comment: @furas yep, tried it when you first suggested it. Same result :/. No errors, the launcher just jumps in the dock without any screen/display

Comment: it is strange that you don't see any error in console/terminal when you run it manually - it would display message if it can't load pygame or it can't load image. You can add `print()` with some message in different places to see which `print()` will display text and which will not. This way you can check if code is really running.

Comment: @furas I'm not sure if you've understood my issue, but I've updated the question to clarify further. When I print, it prints whatever I need it to print, but for pygame, displaying a seperate window for the game doesn't work. No window opens up like it's supposed to as I've shown in the question. It tries to run the window, so I'm almost 100% sure there isn't an error, just a problem with MacOS and that particular pygame function.

Comment: often people write incomplet information or they have different problem then they describe so I try to exclude some popular mistakes. ie. sometimes people put code in one file and later they runs different incomplet or empty file. If you see `print()` which you add to code with `pygame()` then it runs correct file. If you see `print()` which is before `set_mode()` but you don't see `print()` which is after `set_mode()` then it hangs on `set_mode()`,

Comment: @furas I understand, I can assure you though I'm running the correct file "main.py" and print("hey") displays "hey" on the terminal whether I input it before set_mode() or after set_mode().

Comment: Have you tried calling `pygame.display.update()`?

Answer (score 1):

Ted Klein Bergman comment is right. Put `pygame.display.update()` in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
                                                                                                                
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
```